# How to stage a Maven release without creating scm tag?

Tags: maven, release, stage

Our current SDLC goes something like this:

1. Develop code & unit tests
2. Release to QA for system testing
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 as required until QA is passed
4. Promote to UAT
5. Repeat steps 1 to 5 as required until UAT is passed
6. Deploy to production

We are using the maven-release-plugin to manage the releases, but want to maintain the same build number throughout the cycle. Currently each time we build, the artifact release version increases. e.g. 1.2.3 released to QA, fix errors and rebuild becomes 1.2.4, etc.

We have looked at using the release:stage goal, however the first use creates a tag in SCM, and each subsequent use of release:stage builds from this SCM tag, and does not include any code added after this tag is created. We've tried using release:rollback after release:stage to remove the scm tag, but this does not work.

Is there a way to perform this type of release cycle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For our project, we uses snapshot for CI, beta for the step 1-5 cycle.